# Trying install a package

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i want install this package for Sawyer robot because that's required as follow
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-sns-ik-lib
i have ros melodic and the error it's this

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-sns-ik-lib

thank you¡¡

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336331/trying-install-a-package/) by [tegusg](https://answers.ros.org/users/45864/tegusg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see this question: https://answers.ros.org/question/331079/cannot-find-package-sns_ik_lib-for-melodic/

On that page, I provided an updated rosinstall file for Sawyer with ROS Melodic. Hopefully that will help you get going.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2019-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tegusg](https://answers.ros.org/users/45864/tegusg/) on 2019-10-30**:
Thanks so much it's was a lot of help